# LM324N op amp not turning on if the negative input is above certain voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I built the following circuit (I'm using LM324N) and am having difficulty understanding why the op amp is not turning on.

[image]

Here are some more observations:

- When the potentiometer is set to less than 4V, the led turns on as expected.
- When I set the potentiometer to output around 4.2V and above the led turns off.
- If I touch the the end of the potentiometer or the negative terminal of the op amp with my hand or a voltmeter the led turns on.
- The output voltage of the op amp measures to be 0 when the potentiometer is set to 4.2V.

Comment: - LM324 + LT1800

Comment: The answers address the LM324, but with respect to your simulation:  CircuitLab doesn't accurately simulate the behavior of op amps with respect to the power rails.  Also, this site allows you to insert a "live" CircuitLab simulation that readers can run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [LM324N](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf) has an input voltage range of 0 to V<sup>+</sup>-1.5 V. So the upper limit of the inputs with 5 V supply is 3.5 V.

Your 4.3 and 5 V inputs are above this limit, so the OP amp will not work as you intend.

To solve this you could do one of the following:

- Change to an OP amp with rail-to-rail inputs
- Use higher supply voltage for the OP amp
- Lower the input voltages, using voltage dividers or similar

Answer (score 5):

If the [LM324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf) is powered with 5V inputs should not be connected to voltages above 3.5V (see the Input Common-Mode Voltage range):

[image: Input Common-Mode Voltage range from LM324 datasheet]